# Load json to table

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm using ajax to load json data into an html table. I figured out a way to do it with a particular json structure, but not sure how to do it using json that is structured in a different format.

Here's the javascript I'm using:

```
let myArray = [];

      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://chrisjschreiner.github.io/data/conjugations.json",
        success: function (response) {
          myArray = response;
          buildTable(myArray);
          console.log(myArray);
        },
      });

      buildTable = (data) => {
        let table = document.getElementById("myTable");

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          let row = `<tr>
                      <td>${data[i].personal_pronoun}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].conjugation}</td>
                    </tr>`;

          table.innerHTML += row;
        }
      };
```

The json data that I used:

```
[
  {
    "personal_pronoun": "Yo",
    "conjugation": "abandono"
  },
  {
    "personal_pronoun": "Tú",
    "conjugation": "abandonas"
  },
  {
    "personal_pronoun": "Él/Ella/Usted",
    "conjugation": "abandona"
  },
  {
    "personal_pronoun": "Nosotros",
    "conjugation": "abandonamos"
  },
  {
    "personal_pronoun": "Vosotros",
    "conjugation": "abandonáis"
  },
  {
    "personal_pronoun": "Ellos/Ellas/Ustedes",
    "conjugation": "abandonan"
  }
]
```

The HTML:

```
<table
                  class="
                    table table-striped table-bordered
                    mb-sm
                    table-text-color
                  "
                >
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>PERSONAL PRONOUN</th>
                      <th>CONJUGATION</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="myTable"></tbody>
                </table>
```

And the table this generates:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go3m1.png)

How can I get the same results, but with using json structure like this?

```
  {
    "Yo": "abordo",
    "Tú": "abordas",
    "Él/Ella/Usted": "aborda",
    "Nosotros": "abordamos",
    "Vosotros": "abordáis",
    "Ellos/Ellas/Ustedes": "abordan"
  }
```

Comment: Objects *(that are not Array-like Objects)* don't have a length. Use a `for in` or `for of` loop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.

**1st option** is to use `Object.keys` method

```
let buildTable = (data) => {
    let table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        let row = `<tr>
                      <td>${key}</td>
                      <td>${data[key]}</td>
                   </tr>`;
        table.innerHTML += row;
    });
};
```

**2nd option** is to use for..in loop

```
let buildTable = (data) => {
    let table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    for(const key in data) {
        let row = `<tr>
                      <td>${key}</td>
                      <td>${data[key]}</td>
                   </tr>`;
        table.innerHTML += row;
    }
};
```

But it gets also gets keys from prototype chain (shouldn't be a problem in you case though), to avoid that use `hasOwnProperty` to filter out keys

```
let buildTable = (data) => {
    let table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    for(const key in data) {
        if(!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

        let row = `<tr>
                      <td>${key}</td>
                      <td>${data[key]}</td>
                   </tr>`;
        table.innerHTML += row;
    }
};
```

**3d option** is for..of loop

```
let buildTable = (data) => {
    let table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        let row = `<tr>
                      <td>${key}</td>
                      <td>${value}</td>
                   </tr>`;
        table.innerHTML += row;
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried all options you provided, and they all work beautifully. Thanks!